# C++ ShellExecute is not working the same way as cmd.exe

Tags: c++, windows, shellexecute

I'm running this command

> w_icrcom.exe j11 hola

from a command prompt and it is working properly, the exe is running using the arguments.

But when I'm doing the same from a C++ program the `w_icrcom.exe` is behaving differently. I'm getting an error saying that "abnormal program termination". This though is happening only when you pass arguments to 'w_icrcom.exe'.

It seems to me, that when I execute a command everything is fine, but when some other program is trying to execute the same command it doesn't work and I'm getting the "abnormal program execution" error.

I tried the same set up on `ShellExecute` calling the `notepad.exe` and passing arguments and it worked fine. Is there any logical explanation on this issue?

```
string test_var = ("j11 hola");
ShellExecute(0, "open", "C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\My First\\connect\\bin\\w_icrcom.exe", test_var.c_str(), 0, SW_SHOW);
```

Comment: "behaving differently" - you have to elaborate on that...

Comment: Single backslashes are invalid (mostly).

Comment: The next to last parameter of ShellExecuteA is the 'working directory'.  It might need to be set to whatever is the current directory in the cmd prompt that is working.

Comment: I updated the issue with more info that I manage to test...I hope they will help you to find out what is wrong...

Comment: @michaelriis - you still haven't changed the next to last parameter of ShellExecute, which is the current directory.

Comment: @DavidChing - In one of the experiments I put "C:\\" because I thought it was the drive, and since you specify earlier the full path. But I just tried what you said, and now it is working great! Thank you very much!

Comment: Great, glad it works!, I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next to last parameter of `ShellExecute` is the 'working directory'. It might need to be set to whatever is the current directory in the cmd prompt that is working.